# pandas filter dataframe based on chained splits

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which contains a column (column name `filenames`) with filenames. The filenames look something like:

```
long_file1_name_0.jpg
long_file2_name_1.jpg
long_file3_name_0.jpg
...
```

To filter, I do this (lets say `select_string="0"):

```
df_fp = df_fp[~df_fp["filenames"].str.split(".jpg")[0].split("_")[-1]==select_string]
```

but I get thrown this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/file/location/dir/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2889, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 97, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1032, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1039, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_file.py", line 118, in <module>
    main()
  File "inference.py", line 57, in main
    _=some_function(config_dict=config_dict, logger=logger, select_string=config_dict['global']['select_string'])
  File "/file/location/dir/etc/fprint/dataloaders.py", line 31, in some_function2
    logger=logger, select_string=select_string)
  File "/file/location/dir/etc/fprint/preprocess.py", line 25, in df_preprocess
    df_fp = df_fp[~df_fp["filenames"].str.split(".jpg")[0].split("_")[-1]==select_string]
  File "/file/location/dir/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 882, in __getitem__
    return self._get_value(key)
  File "/file/location/dir/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 991, in _get_value
    loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
  File "/file/location/dir/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2891, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 0
```

I think it does not like me chaining the splits, but I vaguely remember doing this sometime ago and it did work.. so, I am perplexed why it throws this error.

PS: I do know how to solve using `.contains` but I would like to use this approach of comparig strings.

Any pointers would be great!

Comment: Do all the rows contain `.jpg`, could you please verify?

Comment: `df_fp = df_fp[~df_fp.filenames.str.rstrip(".jpg").str.split("_").str.get(-1)==select_string]` or a more straightforward 
 `df_fp = df_fp[~df_fp.filenames.str.contains(select_string + '.jpg', regex=False)]`

Comment: @RichieV thank you for this. May I ask what `regex=False` does here?

Comment: pandas uses regex by default on all methods of `.str` accessor, by the look of your data it seems it would not hurt if you let it use regex by default, but it would also match a string containing `"0[anyothercharacter2 34&&*@#].jpg"` if it was in the column (the `'.'` in `select_string` passed to regex acts as a wildcard)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way, with `.str.extract()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'filename': ['long_file1_name_0.jpg',
                                'long_file2_name_1.jpg',
                                'long_file3_name_0.jpg',
                                'long_file3_name_33.jpg',]
                  })
```

Now, create a boolean mask.  The `squeeze()` method ensures we have a series, so the mask will work:

```
mask = (df['filename'].str.extract( r'\w+_(\d+).jpg' )
          .astype(int)
          .eq(0)
          .squeeze())

print(df.loc[mask])

                filename
0  long_file1_name_0.jpg
2  long_file3_name_0.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all rows contain `.jpg`, if not please change it to only `.` instead

```
select_string=str(0) #select string should be of type str
```

```
df_fp=df_fp[df_fp["filenames"].apply(lambda x: x.split(".jpg")[0].split("_")[-1]).astype(str)==select_string]
```

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
df_fp["filenames"].str.split(".jpg")[0]
```

returns you the first row of the DataFrame, not the first element of the list.

What you are looking for is `expand` (it will create a new columns for every element in the list after the `split`) parameter:

```
df[df['filenames'].str.split('.jpg', expand=True)[0].str.split('_', expand=True)[1] == '0']
```

Alternatively you could do that via apply:

```
df[df['filenames'].apply(lambda x: x.split('.jpg')[0].split('_')[-1]) == '0']
```

but `contains` is definitely more appropriate here.